# Heroku error with rake db:pull - ! Taps Load Error: cannot load such file -- sqlite3

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, sqlite, taps

I'm getting

```
 !    Taps Load Error: cannot load such file -- sqlite3
```

even though I have 'sqlite3' installed
My database.yml is set to use Postgres in all environments

Ruby is `1.9.3p125`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support sqlite3.

So you need to change your Gemfile to be:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

And run `bundle install` again

Comment: Where can I find that gem file?